# How do I rename a folder in Office 365's Outlook?

Tags: office-365, outlook-365

I have created folders in **Office 365's Outlook**, but cannot find how to rename them.

When I *right-click* or *control-click* a folder's name, here are the options that are displayed (these are folders I have created):

[image: Move up in the list, Move down in the list, Remove from Favorites, Empty folder, Mark all as read, Assign policy, Permissions]

*Edit: After Montag’s comment, I am adding a screenshot to show that the folders I click on are folders I created, not the default folders :*

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Brienne is right](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97387/117311).

Under your last folder (before Groups) click on "More".

This will take you to the Folders side window. On top you will see your "Favorites" folders, under that will be *your* login name and the same list of folders as are shown in "Favorites".

Right-click on the folder that you want to rename that is listed under your name.

You will then see the option to rename. Once you go back, the folder is renamed.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out (for me, at least)! You may be trying to edit your folders looking at them in "Favourites". Remove them from your "Favourites", click "More" under "Folders", then you will be able to right click and rename or delete the folder you created.

Answer (score 2):

[image: It should be the second option in the menu]

A few things to double check:
Are you clicking in the list of folders on the left immediately after you sign in?
Also, are you sure you're logged in as the same user that originally created those folders?

I have no idea if the French site is the same as the one English users are presented with-- I even selected the Junk Mail folder and still had the option to rename... make sure you're **not** selecting them in the Favorites section as there is no option to Rename folders that are displaying there.

Comment: Which leads us to... http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95913/how-do-i-change-the-language-in-office-365s-outlook

Comment: I edited my question, after changing language I still had the problem. My folders view differs from yours (no left blue arrow on top for me)

Comment: Could you try to use Chrome and see if you have the same options? I am bewildered as to why and how in the world a website could display so extremely differently on two modern browsers...

Comment: It's similar for me in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 and IE 11.0.9600.xxx. I get: Create new subfolder, Rename, Delete, Empty Folder, Add to Favorites, Move.., Mark all as read, Assign policy >, and Permissions in both. I have screenshots but in the comment space I don't think I can add them. I see differences only by selecting different folder grouping types... ex. Favorites folder presents different options.

Comment: So weird! As you can see my presentation - and major features! differ from the ones you got...

Answer (score 1):

Only user created folders can be renamed. I've checked to see if this the same on the Outlook desktop application and found out that it is so.

The statement from Microsoft about this issue: [You can't rename or move default folders such as Inbox, Drafts, or Deleted Items.](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Rename-or-move-a-folder-in-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-ae2a98ad-d54f-4fb1-a72a-168c50818d14)

You are most probably selecting a default folder. Try selecting one of your personal folders too see if the **"Rename"** option shows up in the right-click menu.

Comment: Nope, it's the same behavior and menu for all the folders I click, even the ones I created myself. See my edit.