# How do I change the language in Office 365's Outlook?

Tags: office-365, office-online, outlook-on-the-web

I'm trying to change the language of my Outlook/Office 365.

At the moment my version of the site is in both French and English and I am trying to make it all English.

[image]

In the Settings right-side pane, I have tried to change the language by searching for "language" and then changed it to English, but several parts are still in French.

[image]

I have tried restarting the computer and the browser fruitlessly. And [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-CAA1FCCC-BCDB-42F3-9E5B-45957647FFD7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) doesn't work (when I click on the black on white default avatar seen on the previous screenshot and then my name, nothing happens, my name isn't a link).

Also, I am in the USA so I don't think this is a geographic-related language setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you directly select the "Mail" item on the "Settings" panel the mail "Options" panel will open on the left side of the browser.

[image]

On the "Options" side panel dive into "Region and time zone" settings under the "General" group. On this page you'll see an extra checkbox which reads as **"Rename default folders so their names match the specified language"**. I haven't tried to change my own language setting by using this checkbox but my guess is that this is the correct setting to solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Makes absolutely no sense that they wouldn't have that checkbox when you access these settings through a search though…